# JS folder is missing in deployed server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, ant

I have a server that when deployed is unable to find bootstrap.min.js which should be located in localhost:8080/js. However, when I look at the Source of the webpage through chrome, there is no js folder, only a css folder:

[image]

Whcih causes this failed to load resource error:

[image]

In eclipse the js folder exists under web-content:

[image]

I am using ant to build the war file, is there something specific I need to do to get it to deploy with the JS folder and the correct files in it? When I look at the contents of the .war file the js folder exists in it. I have tried changing the path that it is accessing bootstrap.min.js from to match what is in the .war file, but that has not worked.

Comment: if the files are present in the .WAR file, but not the deployed webroot, your servlet container is doing something strange

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem with your build.xml.
Please check this property:

```
<property name="src.web.dir" value="${src.main.dir}/web"/>
```

Comment: I dont seem to have a property with that name, but I do have a property called src.dir and another called web-inf.dir if those are related. 
I've technically solved this by finding a URL to bootstrap.min.js instead, but I would still be interested to know what I was doing wrong before.